# how to pass container arguments to jenkins docker cloud template

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

I'm using Docker plugin for Jenkins.

when I configure new docker cloud with docker template everything works as expected(Jenkins spins off a container and do the job)
but now I have a new build job that requires more disk space and my job failing on: "not enough disk space" in the container.

I want to add --storage-opt size=15G to the docker template in Jenkins to allow the docker to be bigger than the default 10G it has. 
unfortunately, whatever I tried it did not respond and in some cases, it failed with the error  :

```
Reason: Template provisioning failed.
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: {"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"--storage-opt\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"}
```

what am I missing, how should I pass the arguments? 
thanks!

Comment: How you are passing the `--storage-opt-size`? can you try with `docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args ' --storage-opt size=15G'
        }`

Comment: I'm using docker Cloud configuration in Jenkins configure, not dockerfile.
I'm moving my jobs from physical servers to dockers.
I tried adding the parameter to Docker Command inside the docker template .
@Adiii

Comment: What does your docker template look like?